# Problema com Get, Set javascript

Tags: javascript

Alguém poderia me informar como eu faco um set de uma classe MVC Javascript? Eu envio, mas sempre que resgato o valor para verificar ele fica undefined. Segue exemplo:

**charController.js**:

```
class CharController {

  constructor() {

    this._charNameSelected;
    this.initialize();

  }

  get charNameSelected() {
    return this._charNameSelected;
  }

  set charNameSelected(value) {
    this._charNameSelected = value;
  }


  initialize() {

    console.log(this.charNameSelected);

  }
}
```

**charModel.js**:

```
objCharController = new CharController();
objCharController.charNameSelected = "teste";
```

Comment: Coloca o código e não a imagem.

Comment: Ok, sou novo aqui, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei bem o que queres dizer com *"uma classe MVC Javascript"*, mas o problems que tens no teu exemplo é o método `initialize` corre **antes** do teu `set`, e por isso o `console.log` dá undefined. Se correres o `initalize` depois vais ver que está tudo em ordem (vê o exemplo em baixo).

```js
class CharController {
  constructor() {
    this._charNameSelected;
    this.initialize();
  }

  get charNameSelected() {
    return this._charNameSelected;
  }

  set charNameSelected(value) {
    this._charNameSelected = value;
  }
  initialize() {
    console.log(this.charNameSelected);
  }
}

objCharController = new CharController();
objCharController.charNameSelected = "teste";
objCharController.initialize();
```

O que provavelmente queres fazer é passar argumentos a esse `constructor` e assim atribuires um valor antes do `initialize` correr. Nesse caso seria assim:

```js
class CharController {
  constructor(name) {
    this._charNameSelected = name; // aqui podias usar `charNameSelected` se quiseres invocar a logica do 'setter'
    this.initialize();
  }

  get charNameSelected() {
    console.log('get');
    return this._charNameSelected;
  }

  set charNameSelected(value) {
    console.log('set =>', value);
    this._charNameSelected = value;
  }
  initialize() {
    console.log('initialize =>', this.charNameSelected);
  }
}

objCharController = new CharController('teste');
console.log(objCharController.charNameSelected);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @BrunoBafilli se a resposta era o que procuravas podes marcar como aceite. Fico contente de ter ajudado.